# What are the factors affecting transparency and color of a substance

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, material-science, optical-materials

What is the reason behind visual properties like color and transparency of different substances? I have always heard that the structure of the substance is responsible for these properties. I always imagined that the bond length between the atoms of the substance permits photons of only some certain wavelength. But, most bonds are in the order of $1.5\unicode{xC5} $, and by my "explanation", most materials should appear to be opaque (in the visible spectrum), but they don't. Why?

Comment: AvZ: have a look through the results you get if you [search this site for *transparent*](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=transparent)

Comment: I did exactly that before I submitted the question, It went to google search of the site which didn't return any similar questions...

Comment: Is the "color" portion of this question also a duplicate?